# How can I set a onChange Listeners on <DatePicker> & <TimePicker> Programmatically?

Tags: android

I use a customized DialogFragment which contains `<DatePicker>` and `<TimePicker>` elements. I retrieve the instances of this UI widgets via findViewById. The problem is, I don't know how to set the listeners for DatePicker detecting date change.It goes the same with TimePicker.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/dialog_fragment_layout_datetimepicker"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datepicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timepicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_datepickersave"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dialog_button_save"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I retrieve the DatePicker and TimePicker elements via:

```
    mDateTimePickerDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    mDateTimePickerDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_fragment_datetimepicker);
    mDateTimePickerDialog.setTitle(R.string.title_choose_datetime);

    mDatePicker = (DatePicker) mDateTimePickerDialog.findViewById(R.id.datepicker);
    mTimePicker = (TimePicker) mDateTimePickerDialog.findViewById(R.id.timepicker);
```

But upon looking on the documentation, I only see a way if DatePicker and TimePicker is all dialog by themselves and set the listeners on their constructors.

How can I add listener on DatePicker and TimePicker created on this way? Is this possible? Are there alternate way to do this? Is this best done using third-party source?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set it with the init method, where you also set it's initial date/time. See [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#init%28int,%20int,%20int,%20android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener%29)

But I didn't like the default pickers and ended up using this one [HERE](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker)

Comment: Thank you Bojan, init() method is exactly what I have been looking for. So pity I missed this method and never thought it was available as well with DatePicker and Time Picker. Such a great help. Save me some hours of experimenting!

Answer (score 1):

You should use callback interface for this

Read this manuals:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setOnTimeChangedListener%28android.widget.TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener%29

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#init%28int,%20int,%20int,%20android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener%29

Comment: Thanks, I will be looking onto this sources. But I am trying to avoid callbacks as of the moment as I was trying to detect date changes and act on it accordingly and adding new interfaces there and fro seems to be overkill for my situation. But still, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this method of `DatePicker`:

```
 DatePicker.init (int, int, int, DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener);
```

or:

```
DatePicker.updateDate (int year, int month, int dayOfMonth);
```

And for `TimePicker`:

```
TimePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener onTimeChangedListener);
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you SilenKnight!